# CSP block google translate

Tags: php, wordpress, google-api, header, content-security-policy

I'm using a plugin to translate a Wordpress website by using Google translate. I've setted up a content security policy for the website and this will cause that the Wordpress plugin can't translate the website because the CSP will block it. Is there a way to enable the Google translate features when the CSP is setted on a website? I had the same problem with Google maps and I've solved it by adding the google.com address to the CSP, but with translate I don't know how to proceed.

CSP settings:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com; font-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; frame-src https://www.google.com; ");
?>
```

> (index):1 Refused to load the script 'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=GoogleLanguageTranslatorInit' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://translate.googleapis.com/". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: how does your plugin contact Google Translate? (you currently added `google.com` for scripts, CSS and iframe, but would be blocked for ajax requests, if you want to enable it, add `connect-src`). Adding your full error log for the CSP block could be useful

Comment: Whats the error you are seeing in the console?

Comment: @DaImTo `(index):1 Refused to load the script 'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=GoogleLanguageTranslatorInit' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://translate.googleapis.com/". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add every domain you want to allow to your CSP header:

- `https://translate.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` are not the same thing
- `https://translate.google.com` and `https://translate.googleapis.com/` are not the same thing

try with:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://translate.google.com; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com; font-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; frame-src https://www.google.com; ");
?>
```

**NOTE** that once the script will be allowed, CSP will maybe block other types of resource from the same domain (ex CSS, iframe), if that is the case, just add this domain to these types too.

Comment: Using "unsafe-inline" beats the purpose of using CSP in first place

Comment: And sadly google translate doesn't work without unsafe-inline because they add the scripts inline in the page, great job google!